# Loading details on the index page

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I'm developing app in which I load all the pages in the index.html using jQuery. 
On the loaded pages, there is one particular page which comes along with links which when clicked takes you to another page to give you details about the link you clicked. 
Now I want to be able to load the details of the clicked link into a particular div in the index.html called news_details. How do I do that?

This is the code I'm using for the links:

```
<a href="index.html#news_details?<%= Server.HTMLEncode(MM_keepURL) & MM_joinChar(MM_keepURL) & "news_id=" & rs_news.Fields.Item("news_id").Value %>"><%=(rs_news.Fields.Item("headline").Value)%>
```

and here the jQuery loading the page with the url into the div:

```
 <script language="javascript">
$('#news_details').bind('pageshow', function (){


    var url = window.location.search.substring(1);

    $('#news_details').load('news.asp'+ url);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
$(function () {
  var url = window.location.search.substring(1);
  $('#news_details').load('news.asp?page='+ url);

  $(document).on("click",".classOfNewLink",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#news_details").load('news.asp?page='+encodeURIComponent(this.href));
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes. i want to get the url and add it to the link and display the details in div of the index page instead of going to another page

Comment: the answer you've given me is working all right but not able to pass the url parameter

Comment: You likely need "?"+url or "?page="+url

Comment: please it's still functioning like before. the url is not able to pass. the page do displays though but not with the url parameter

Comment: I have no idea what to test. You need to look in the console, debug with console.log.

Comment: Ok. thanks. but i think maybe when # is included in a link url parameters can't be passed. cos there is hash included in my link. but thanks anyway

Comment: You are passing search and not hash. Instead try (location.href).split("#")[1] or such construct